# Git contains between arbitrary commits

Tags: git, parent, commit, contains

I was wondering if there is a generalized method for finding if a commit is a parent to another.

```
git branch --contains <hash>
```

Is almost what I want. It lists all branches that contain the commit, but I want to know if an  arbitrary commit "contains" another commit.

My temporary hack is to create a branch at the commit and then check if it's contained in the list, but this seems sloppy.

```
git branch __temp_branch__ <hash1>
git branch --contains <hash2> # check if __temp_branch__ is in output
git branch -d __temp_branch__
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If commitA is an ancestor of commitB, then `git merge-base commitA commitB` is `commitA`. For example:

```
if [ "$(git merge-base $commitA $commitB)" = "$commitA" ]; then ...
```

This is substantially more efficient than grepping the output of `git rev-list`, should that matter to you.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer as it's quite a bit faster than the other answers and also ensures that both hashes are valid.

Answer (score 2):

`git rev-list <childSHA> | grep <parentSHA>`

This will return the `<parentSHA>` if it was a parent of `<childSHA>`

Answer (score 0):

One possibility maybe is:

```
git log --ancestry-path <parentSHA> <childSHA>
```

If it returns nothing, you know parentSHA is not a parent.